# Return the last two values of a cell based on a name

Tags: arrays, google-sheets

I'm working on a program that looks for a specific name in a Column B and returns the last two values recent values from another column. Some of the names I'm searching are recorded more than twice and I don't want to work with the previous values.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ZgYXry-Zkj5i2FuIkwuHeiAAV8VzFUsvQkjxqJGez3c/edit#gid=0

I tried using this function on the sheet

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TEXTJOIN(" ,",TRUE,if(A2:A18="Alamosa",F2:F,"")))
```

but depending on the name, it returns more than 2 values, and I want to work with only the last two.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this can be done with a query(). See if this works

```
=ArrayFormula(query({row(A2:A), A2:F}, "select Col7 where Col3 = 'Alamosa' order by Col1 desc limit 2"))
```

and if you want to join the results

```
=join(", ", ArrayFormula(query({row(A2:A), A2:F}, "select Col7 where Col3 = 'Alamosa' order by Col1 desc limit 2")))
```

Comment: So I added a variation to that but it is still a bug on the formula. I have added the formula on the Y column and the Acequias column returns to me the first value first, instead of the last value. I've also allowed edits to the spreadsheet.

Comment: @DavidMaciasMata: the formula you used left out an essential part of the formula I posted. Check out the copy I made and where I entered in cell Y7 =ArrayFormula(QUERY({row(A1:A), A1:E}, "SELECT Col6 WHERE Col2 = 'Acequias' AND Col6 IS NOT NULL ORDER BY Col1 DESC LIMIT 2", 0))

Comment: Thank you very much! Worked perfectly!